# Xtext injection binding error

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, xtext

I'm follow the book "Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend" by Lorenzo Bettini and at some point in chapter 6, I'm asked to use the API provided by the Xtext referring to dependency injection using Google Guice.

The code of service implemented

```
class EntitiesOutputConfigurationProvider extends OutputConfigurationProvider {
       public val ENTITIES_GEN = "./entities-gen"
       override getOutputConfigurations() {
              super.getOutputConfigurations() => [
              head.outputDirectory = ENTITIES_GEN
              ]
       }
}
```

The code of the binding is :

```
public class EntitiesRuntimeModule extends AbstractEntitiesRuntimeModule {
       public Class<? extends IOutputConfigurationProvider>
       bindIOutputConfigurationProvider() {
              return EntitiesOutputConfigurationProvider. class;
       }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error after

> AbstractEntitiesRuntimeModule

Error:

> mismatched input '{' expecting '=>'

And according to the book and the Xtext documentation the code is correct. 
Anyone has any idea?

P.S.: My Xtext version is 2.9

Comment: Looks like you have put the first snippet into a *.java file. Make sure you put it into EntitiesOutputConfigurationProvider.xtend. If that is not the case, please be more specific about where exactly (which file, line) you get the error and when.

Comment: Actually it is in a .xtend file. The file im getting the error is EntitiesRuntimeModule.xtend under src/org.xtext.example.entities.
And the line is the one where I declare bindIOutputConfigurationProvider()

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java syntax inside an Xtend class. 
In order to define a new method in Xtend, you always have to use the `def` keyword.

The reason for the specific error message is that Xtend supports shorthands for function types. For example, `()=>String` is the type of a function that takes no parameters and returns a String, and is short for `Function0<? extends String>`.

In Xtend, `public Class<? extends IOutputConfigurationProvider> bindIOutputConfigurationProvider` is a complete field definition (not a method definition), and that Xtend parser thinks you are trying to start a second field definition which has a function type, but you didn't completely specify the type. In a function type, the next thing after a `()` always has to be a `=>`, so the parser complains that it finds a `{` instead.